# Can I highlight only 1 number of a 2 or 3 number entry in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts

If I type the number 85 in one cell and the number 104 in another is there a way that I can automatically change the font colour of the 5 and 4 only? I know that I can extract the number by using =right(a1,1) and then have that cell font colour but I want to leave the numbers there. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I don't think that what you are trying is possible since Excel highlights entire cell or I can suggest you to highlight only Special characters or numbers among Cell value. Like highlight only @ sing  if is part of A@44 or highlight 44 if as AS44 !!

Answer (score 1):

The below Macro gets you half way there but with a few caveats:

You would need to change the cell formats of your numbers to TEXT

It will only work on the active Cell

And only does one number at a time, you would need to crate 2 macros for 2 numbers.

But it's a starting point:

```
Sub FontChange()

      Dim j As Long

      j = InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "5", vbTextCompare)

      j x > 0 Then ActiveCell.Characters(j, 5).Font.Color = vbGreen

End Sub
```

Comment: I knew you could manually select some characters/words in a cell and change the color of just those selected. Didn't realize it couldn't be done to numeric type formats...

Comment: @gns100 there might be a way I'm just not that experienced in vba :S

Comment: Thanks for your help.